# Data extraction from SQL database with no success

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Good evening to all,i have a prolem,i think,with the extraction of the value content in my Android database.

First of all,i have tryed the app on a device (SGS3) and the database are correctly create and popoulated by a query,but when i try to call extract from the cursor the value,LogCat give me the error NullPointerExeption. I have read some of other thread but i havent find the answer to my problem.

This is the code for the creation of the database,the query and the position of the data:

```
    public static Cursor fetchProducts(){ //attenzione cambioato,messo static
        return mDb.query(PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,null);               
}

static class PositionsMetaData {  
        static final String POSITIONS_TABLE = "position";
        static final String ID = "_id";
        static final String POSITIONS_NAME_KEY = "name";
        static final String POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY = "lat";
        static final String POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY = "lon";
}

private static final String POSITIONS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_TABLE + " (" 
                + PositionsMetaData.ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY + " text, "
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY + " double not null, "
                + PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY + " double not null); ";
```

Dunno why,but eclipse want the cursor with the static,i'm not sure of this and why this,by the way,thi is the code for the extraction of the data:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listagps);

        TextView nomelista=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nomelista);
        TextView latitudinelista=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitudinelista);
        TextView longitudinelista=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitudinelista);


        // CREAZIONE LISTA PUNTI GPS SU LAYOUT LISTAGPS

        ListView posizionigps=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listagps);

        final listagpsdb db = new listagpsdb(getApplicationContext());

        db.open();

        Cursor c=listagpsdb.fetchProducts();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter (
                this,
                R.layout.listagps_item,
                c,
                new String[]{listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY,listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY,listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY},
                new int []{R.id.nomelista,R.id.longitudinelista,R.id.latitudinelista});

        posizionigps.setAdapter(adapter);

        int nomecol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY);
        int loncol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY);
        int lancol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY);


        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                 nomelista.append(c.getString(nomecol));
                 latitudinelista.append(c.getString(lancol));
                 longitudinelista.append(c.getString(loncol));

            } while (c.moveToNext());

            }

        db.close(); 

    }


    }
```

The LogCat give me the error for nomelista,latitudinelista and longitudinelista,all null but in the DB are all populated.

Any suggestion to solve this problem? Is a uncorrect management of the cursor or because the textview isn't set with the data? I have tried everithing i know,but with no success.

Thanks a lot to all want to help me :)

FULL LOGCAT OF THE PROBLEM

```
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.drive.info/com.drive.info.listagps}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at com.drive.info.listagps.onCreate(listagps.java:68)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-05 14:42:22.613: E/AndroidRuntime(988):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please add here your full logcat.

Comment: Added in the main post the full logcat :) The row 68 is the row of the nomelista.append(c.getString(nomecol));

Comment: Looks like the TextView nomelista is null. Is the nomelista defiled in R.layout.listagps?

Comment: @bakriOnFire R.layout.listagps is only a listview and every row of this layout are populated by another layout (R.layout.listagps_item).
In the listagps_item i have 3 textView (nomelista,longitudinelista and latitudinelista) without any character inside,originally is empty,filled later with the data extracted by the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to inflate the R.layout.listagps_item first and then use this inflated view to findViewById of your text views.

Something like this:-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listagps);

LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View vListItems = li.inflate(R.layout.listagps_item, null);

    TextView nomelista=(TextView) vListItems.findViewById(R.id.nomelista);
    TextView latitudinelista=(TextView) vListItems.findViewById(R.id.latitudinelista);
    TextView longitudinelista=(TextView) vListItems.findViewById(R.id.longitudinelista);


    // CREAZIONE LISTA PUNTI GPS SU LAYOUT LISTAGPS

    ListView posizionigps=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listagps);

    final listagpsdb db = new listagpsdb(getApplicationContext());

    db.open();

    Cursor c=listagpsdb.fetchProducts();
    startManagingCursor(c);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter (
            this,
            vListItems,
            c,
            new String[]{listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY,listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY,listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY},
            new int []{R.id.nomelista,R.id.longitudinelista,R.id.latitudinelista});

    posizionigps.setAdapter(adapter);

    int nomecol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_NAME_KEY);
    int loncol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LONGITUDE_KEY);
    int lancol=c.getColumnIndex(listagpsdb.PositionsMetaData.POSITIONS_LATITUDE_KEY);


    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
             nomelista.append(c.getString(nomecol));
             latitudinelista.append(c.getString(lancol));
             longitudinelista.append(c.getString(loncol));

        } while (c.moveToNext());

        }

    db.close(); 

}
}
```

In the above code what i change is, i've inflated the R.layout.listagps_item in a view named vListItems and used this view object to findViewById of nomelista,longitudinelista and latitudinelista.

Also note that i've also passed the vListItems in SimpleCursorAdapter insted of R.layout.listagps_item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: with your help now i have solved the error gived me! A lot of thanks and,naturally,the best answer,but i have a question,to avoid future error. You have used the layoutInflater and now i have read some on the android dev site. What is the difference from setContentView? With the setContentView you define wich layout are used by the activity,but does not handle the layout in another layout? For the future case,similar this,i have to use only the LayoutInflater and with findViewById i search the object inside this instance?
Now i have to understand why the cursor read only the first row :)

Comment: the setContentView() itself inflates the layout that u pass in it. And if you want to create an object of the views that are not in the activity's layout(i.e. setContentView() of that activity) then you'll have to inflate that layout and use the object of that inflated layout to findViewByIds of its views.

Comment: Yeah,now i have understand setContentView() set the activity general layout,but if i want to insert some items not in the original layout,i have to inflate the second and,in the activity,call the object in the second with the findviewbyid.
Thx a lot ;)